# Blender sculpting

Tags: sculpting

How can I remove this ring, which makes editing symmetrical along this ring?[image]

Comment: Do you mean cut s hole? If so, can you tell us what you mean by 'making editing symmetrical'?

Answer (score 2):

Bring back the radial symmetry to its default 1:

[image]